# Chocolatey unzips a previously installed program to the wrong directory

Tags: chocolatey

I am trying to install Neovim to the "C:/Program Files" directory via Chocolatey on Windows 7. I had previously installed Neovim via Chocolatey to a different directory ("C:/Tools"), but later uninstalled it.

```
cd C:/Program Files
choco install Neovim
```

When running these lines in Powershell (with Administrative privileges) Chocolatey successfully installs Neovim, but to the "C:/Tools" directory where it had previously been installed.

It seems Chocolatey is remembering where it had installed Neovim and ignoring the current directory. Is there a way to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: What did you run? Do you have remembered arguments turned on? What about the package itself? There are too many elements here to consider, so please add more context to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The package itself uses the [`ChocolateyToolsLocation`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-get-tools-location) environment variable to determine install location, but does not have a [package parameter](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-parse-package-parameters-argument) that lets you configure just for this package.

Look at the package files - https://chocolatey.org/packages/neovim#files. If you want a different directory, you will need to update the environment variable for ChocolateyToolsLocation to `C:\Program Files`, then run your installation. This will affect all package installs that use `Get-ToolsLocation`. HTH

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood how Chocolatey works. I previously created a C:/tools directory and used it for programs that didn't change the registry. When I originally installed Neovim there, I thought I was choosing the directory for installation by navigating there before running `choco install neovim`. In reality this was Chocolatey's default installation directory.

Comment: It looks like I might be able to choose the directory for installation by using the --install-arguments command to pass a command from Chocolatey to the installer, which I believe is simply 7zip in this case. `choco install neovim --ia -oC:\"'Program Files'"` might work, but I won't have a chance to try it today.